# Method to solve conditional probability events using purely the definitions of probability

Tags: probability

A deck of cards contains the red J, Q, K and Aces from a normal deck. If Pammy is dealt two cards, what is the probability that

i) She has two aces given she has at least one ace.

I tried drawign a dot diagram but it is wrong. I dont know how the sample space from a dot diagram could be $13$. The solution is $\frac{1}{13}$. If I do it manually, I can have $P(B =$ at lease one ace$)  = 2 \cdot 0.25 \cdot 0.75 + 0.25\cdot0.25$, $P(A$ = at least one ace$) = P(A\cap B) = 0.25\cdot0.25$

So $P(A|B) = \frac{\frac{1}{16}}{\frac{7}{16}}$ which is also wrong :(

ii) She has a pair if she announces that she doesnt have the ace of hearts

iii) She has two cards of tha same suit if she announces she has at least one heart and one king

I actually cannot do this entire excersize - it is from a "dot diagram" conditional probability excersice. For the other problems, I have been abel to draw a dot diagram to solve it. Since I cannot even draw the dot diagram for this question, I can't do any of the parts. My dot diagram is just a two way "table" of JJQQKKAA.

But I welcome any solution (which isn't too overkill!)

---

Another question : Three coins are tossed - find the probability that:

i) three heads show uppoer most if at least one of the coins shows a head

ii) etc.

For this, I also wasnt able to draw a dot diagram! But I solved it anyway using a tree diagram. How does one go about with a dot diagram for this? As well as using probability definitions ie $P(a|b) = \frac{P(a\cap b)}{P(b)}$

Comment: $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is not equal to $\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$.  That is true if *and only if* the events are independent.  The question of two aces for part (i), it seems heavily implied that you are drawing without replacement.  With $A$ the event that the "first" card dealt is an ace and $B$ the event that the "second" card is an ace, these are very much dependent events, not independent.

Comment: So... $\Pr(A\cap B)$, the event the first card is an ace and the second card is an ace, there are $8\times 7=56$ equally likely different ways in which you can draw two cards from this deck in sequence, only two of those events correspond to having drawn both aces (*either ace of hearts then ace of diamonds or vice versa*).  Meanwhile "*at least one ace*" is $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B) = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2}{56}=\frac{26}{56}$.  Taking the ratio gives as expected $\dfrac{2/56}{26/56}=\dfrac{1}{13}$

Comment: Which formula gives the "ratio" to be $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A\cup B)}$?

Comment: The basic definition of conditional probability.  Note that with A and B as I defined above, the condition that you drew at least one ace is the union of A and B.  Note that the intersection of these is a subset of the union and so the numerator simplifies.

Comment: Conditional probability is defined as $Pr(A|B) = \frac{Pr(∩)}{Pr(B)}$. What did you manipulate to make $Pr(B) = (∪)$?

Comment: With $A$ and $B$ as I defined above, we are looking for $\Pr(A\cap B\mid A\cup B)$... not $\Pr(A\mid B)$.  Letting $X=A\cap B$ and letting $Y=A\cup B$ we are looking at $\Pr(X\mid Y)=\dfrac{\Pr(X\cap Y)}{\Pr(Y)} = \dfrac{\Pr((A\cap B)\cap (A\cup B))}{\Pr(A\cup B)}$ which as alluded to already simplifies since $A\cap B\subseteq A\cup B$ to $\dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A\cup B)}$.  With $A$ and $B$ as I defined above, $\Pr(A\cap B\mid A\cup B)$ is the probability we have two aces given we have at least one ace.  $\Pr(A\mid B)$ is we have first card is ace given second card is ace, totally different

Comment: Ahhhh I see. Thank you I understand clearly now. I am not used to using probability formulas outside algebraic simplification-type questions. Normally I do cases or diagrams, but I am trying to practice using the formulae for harder questions.

Comment: I am not familiar with the simplification alluded to from $∩⊆∪$. I know I am seeing it incorrectly but what I'm thinking is there is only one $(∪)$ in the numerator. How can that cancel/simplify with the denominator AND leave a $(∪)$ in the denominator if there is only one?!

Comment: Using different letters to emphasize that this is an identity, $E\subseteq F \iff E\cap F = E$.  You have $(A\cap B)\subseteq (A\cup B)$ (*the elements which are in both $A$ and $B$ are necessarily in at least one of $A$ or $B$*) so by the identity, $(A\cap B)\cap (A\cup B) = (A\cap B)$.  There was no cancellation from numerator and denominator here going on, it was purely "*absorption*" of a subset intersected with a superset resulting in the subset.  As such, the longer mess that was originally in the numerator could be written with far fewer symbols thanks to this.